# CLLocationDegrees with an expression of incompatible type 'double'

Tags: ios, cllocation

The topic says everything. why i get this error message at this 2 lines?

```
NSArray *coordinates = [locationDetails[@"coordinates"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
CLLocationDegrees *lat = [coordinates[1] doubleValue]; //here is the red arrow <----
```

and exactly this message will appear:

> Initializing 'CLLocationDegrees *'(aka 'double *') with an expression
>   of incompatible type 'double'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this:

```
CLLocationDegrees *lat = [coordinates[1] doubleValue];
```

to:

```
CLLocationDegrees lat = [coordinates[1] doubleValue];
```

Get rid of the asterisk. `CLLocationDegrees` is not a class, it is a typedef for `double` (a basic type).

Comment: wow facepalm to my self. This little '*' stole me about 30 min.